# What are "scrivener's tools" from Knuth's METAFONT book?

Tags: fonts

What is a `scrivener's tool` ? I've found this name in Knuth's `METAFONT` book. Google didn't help.

Comment: [Ch4, p21](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/mfbook.pdf#page=35)? The sentence is: "Lines of constant thickness have their uses, but METAFONT also provides several other kinds of scrivener’s tools, and we shall take a look at some of them in this chapter." Looking at [scrivener on wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrivener), seems like Knuth is referring to how METAFONT gives the person typesetting, the scrivener, appropriate tools for typesetting.

Comment: Please, fix the title according to the text or conversely. I don't think the Metafont book mentions “scrivener font”; for “scrivener's tools”, look in a dictionary.

Comment: @egreg Fixed. None of my dictionaries contain `scrivener's tools` item.

Comment: The dictionaries contain *scrivener* and *tool*. Knuth doesn't refer to typography here, but to *calligraphy*.

Comment: Someone like in [this picture](http://vcvoices.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/scribe.jpg)

Comment: @egreg And `scrivener` means the person there, right ?